# Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined - React Native Navigation

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, react-navigation

I am currently working on a app which works with react native and I tried to make a flow using **react-navigation** working on [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/) tutorial but I am having trouble at the point of running my project, I've done a lot of research and i just cant get to the solution, first for all I am using **react-native-cli: 2.0.1 and react-native: 0.48.3**, this is my code:

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, Button, View } from 'react-native';
import {
    StackNavigator,
} from 'react-navigation';

class App extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Welcome',
    };

    render() {
        console.log(this.props.navigation);
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>Go to maps!</Text>
                <Button
                    onPress={() => navigate('Map')}
                    title="MAP"
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

my Router.js

```
import {
    StackNavigator,
  } from 'react-navigation';

  import MapMarker from './MapMarker';
  import App from './App';

  export const UserStack = StackNavigator({
    ScreenMap: 
    {
        screen: MapMarker,
        navigationOptions:
        {
            title: "Map",
            header:null
        },
    },
    ScreenHome: 
    {
        screen: App,
        navigationOptions:
        {
            title: "Home",
            headerLeft:null
        },
    },
});
```

As you can see this is a pretty basic App which i just cant make work, this is a screenshot of my error on the simulator:

[image: Whoops]

I would really really appreciate if you guys could help me with this.
Thanks.

Comment: i think you are not passing "navigation" prop to your App component const { navigate } = this.props.navigation; is undefined because of this

Comment: how can pass navigation to my app component?, IK'm really new with react native @blacksun

Comment: where do you import App? <App navigation={your_navigation} />

Comment: I dont think I am getting the things you say?. in my index.ios/android ive got this: 
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './src/App';

AppRegistry.registerComponent('MAPS', () => App);
@blacksun

Comment: I'm not using expo, i am using the react native with native code

Answer (score 2):

You should change the code `onPress={() => navigate('Map')}` to `onPress={() => navigate('ScreenMap')}` and `ScreenHome` should be the first screen then `ScreenMap` as you want to navigate from `App` to `MapMarker`. Or you can set `initialRouteName: ScreenHome` in the stacknavigator.

Comment: thanks but I am getting the same old error on "const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;", idk what to do, I am really new into react native

Comment: can you tell me the index.android.js/index.ios.js code...your code is perfectly running in my pc...

Answer (score 0):

You create your StackNavigator, but where do you use it? You should have something like

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    AppRegistry,
    View
} from 'react-native';

    import {
        StackNavigator,
      } from 'react-navigation';

    export default class MyApp extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <View style={{flex:1}}>
            <StackNavigator/>
          </View>
        );
      }
    }

    AppRegistry.registerComponent('MyApp', () => MyApp);
```

Now that your StackNavigator is controlling what is shown, your App component will have navigation in its props.  Note, you do not "pass" the navigation prop.  This is handled for you.